# Material UI Select not showing options

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Component where in the `componentDidMount` method I fetch information from the backend and put it on the state of my component. However I have to change the response in order to use the objects coming from the backend on the Select Component from material UI.
I do it like this:

```
var toAdd = []
axios.get(...).then(response.data.forEach(p => toAdd.push({id: p.name, value: p.name}))})
...
this.setState({schemas: toAdd})
```

Then, on render method I send schemas from state to the form component. The form itself has a set of inputfields with the select component as well.

I have the following warning:

**Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value `undefined` for the select (name="schema") component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are "".**

I did console.log and the first value I get is an array [] but with objects inside. After I write something on the input fields, the array changes to [{...}] and then the Select can show the options I wanted. The first array [] is not empty, if I open it on console there is one object inside. The same goes for [{...}]. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use the component state in order to get the data at the time when you get it from the API like this.

```
  state={toAdd:[]}
```

then while fetching data you just set your state like this
                           `this.setState({toAdd:... response.data.map(v=>  {return{id:v.name,value:v.value}})`

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed Muhammed Elsaid, i did as you suggested and it worked. I had state like you suggested before...I changed in order to check why it was not working but the second half solved my problem. Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome anytime @Goncalo we are always  here to help